# Reverse String function in C without library functions

Tags: c, string, algorithm, pointers, reverse

This is my task:

Realize function that reverses null terminated string. The prototype of the function is `void Reverse(char *ptr);`. Do not use standard library functions.

This is my code for now:

```
void Reverse(char *ptr) {
    char *newString;
    char ch = *ptr;
    unsigned int size = 0;

    for (int i = 1; ch != '\0'; i++) {
        ch = *(ptr + i);
        size++;
    }

    newString = (char*)malloc(size);

    for (int left = 0, right = size - 1; left < size; left++, right--) {
        *(newString + left) = *(ptr + right);
    }

    printf("%s", newString);
    printf("\n");
}
```

It reverses the string and saves it in the newString

My first problem is that when I print the newString to see if the functions works the string is reversed, but after it there are some symbols.

For example:
If I have `char *str = "hello";` and `Reverse(str);` in the `main` method
the result of `printf("%s", newString)` will be  `olleh****`.

But if change the
`newString = (char*)malloc(size);`   to
`newString = (char*)malloc(1);`      it works fine.

My second problem is that I don't know how to save the newString into the given one. I am using a new String because the given one can't be changed.

Comment: null termination...............

Comment: Is the intent to return a reversed string, or to simply print in reverse?

Comment: `malloc` doesn't count as a standard library function?

Comment: Peter I can't understand too if i have to print it or return it.

Comment: Consider that you can reverse a string in-place by successive swaps. For example, the string `"james"`. If you swap the first and last characters, you get `"samej"`. And if you swap the second and next-to-last, you get `"semaj"`, which is the reversed string. I'll leave you the task of writing the loop to do that.

Answer (score 4):

For starters it is better to declare the function like

```
char * Reverse( char *ptr );
^^^^^^
```

because standard C string functions usually return pointers to destination strings.

The function should reverse the original string. It may not create a dynamic string because the caller of the function will be unable to free it provided that the function has return type void.

The function can look as it is shown in the following demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * Reverse( char *ptr )
{
    char *first = ptr, *last = ptr;

    while ( *last ) ++last;

    if ( first < last )
    {
        for ( ; first < --last; ++first  )
        {
            char c = *first;
            *first = *last;
            *last  = c;
        }
    }

    return ptr;
}

int main( void ) 
{
    char s[] = "Hello World!";

    puts( s );
    puts( Reverse( s ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
Hello World!
!dlroW olleH
```

Take into account that you may not call the function like

```
puts( Reverse( "Hello World!" ) );
```

because string literals are immutable in C.

If you are going to declare the function like

```
void Reverse( char *ptr );
```

then just remove the return statement in the shown function. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

void Reverse( char *ptr )
{
    char *first = ptr, *last = ptr;

    while ( *last ) ++last;

    if ( first < last )
    {
        for ( ; first < --last; ++first  )
        {
            char c = *first;
            *first = *last;
            *last  = c;
        }
    }
}

int main( void ) 
{
    char s[] = "Hello World!";

    puts( s );
    Reverse( s )
    puts( s );

    return 0;
}
```

If to use your approach with indices then the function can look like

```
#include <stdio.h>

void Reverse( char *ptr ) 
{
    size_t size = 0;

    while ( *( ptr + size ) ) ++size;

    if ( size != 0 )
    {
        for ( size_t left = 0, right = size - 1; left < right; left++, right-- ) 
        {
            char c     = ptr[left];    // or char c = *( ptr + left ); and so on
            ptr[left]  = ptr[right];
            ptr[right] = c;
        }           
    }
}

int main( void ) 
{
    char s[] = "Hello World!";

    puts( s );
    Reverse( s );
    puts( s );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Some standard C string functions return pointers. Not all do.

Comment: @Peter What standard C string functions have return type void?

Comment: I can't change the prototype.

Comment: @StanislavFotev No problem. Just remove the return statement in the function as I already pointed out in my post.:) In this case the demonstrative program will have statements like     puts( s ); Reverse( s );     puts(  s );

Comment: Hmmm, Suspect your nifty (UV) `Reverse( char *ptr )` can be simplified without `if()`.  Will ponder that.

Comment: @chux In this case if a string has for example one character it will be swapped with itself or size_t right = size - 1; will be an incorrect number.

Comment: Swapping with self  is OK.  Perhaps `char *reverse(char *p) {
  char *f = p;
  char *e = p;
  while (*e) e++;

  while (f < e) {
    e--;
    char c = *f;
    *f = *e;
    *e = c;
    f++;
  }

  return p;
}`

Comment: @chux Either you will use the if statement or will swap a character with itself.

Comment: Agree - except will swap with self only on odd length strings. Just wanted to offer an alternative that is less code.  Nice post.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow *'Either you will use the if statement or will swap a character with itself'* is false. Consider `for(; first<--last; ++first) swap(first,last);` for `last` initially pointing at terminating NUL...

Comment: @CiaPan If the initial string is empty then your suggested code has undefined behaviour.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Sorry, I can't see it. Where is it?

Comment: @CiaPan When the pointer last is decremented beyond the string it can get any value. For example in some systems the pointer can get some maximum value of the virtual segment.

Answer (score 1):

In your loop to get the size, you're not counting the null terminator. So your `newString` is missing the null terminator as well. make sure to do `newString = malloc(size + 1);`, and to place the null terminator onto the end of `newString`.

Comment: And remember to make your loop termination case left < size-1

Comment: Thanks for the answer I managed my 1st problem but i don't know how to return the string without changing the prototype.

Comment: In that case they probably want the original string input to be reversed, so use Vlad's answer and just leave the prototype the same & remove the `return` at the end of it.

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems in your code:

- you do not allocate enough space for the resulting string, you must allocate `size+1` bytes and set the `\0` terminator at the end of the string.
- you only copy half the characters from `ptr` to `newString`.
- you are not even supposed to allocate memory, since you cannot call any library functions.  You should instead reverse the string in place.
- Your test fails because modifying a string literal invokes undefined behavior.  You should pass an initialized array as shown below.

Here is an improved version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void Reverse(char *ptr) {
    unsigned int left, right;

    for (right = 0; *(ptr + right) != '\0'; right++) {
         continue;
    }

    for (left = 0; left < right; left++, right--) {
        char ch = ptr[left];
        ptr[left] = ptr[right - 1];
        ptr[right - 1] = ch;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    char buf[] = "Hello world";
    Reverse(buf);
    printf("%s\n", buf);
    return 0;
}
```

It should print `dlrow olleH`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple string reverse function without `string.h` library functions :

```
#include <stdio.h>
void reverse(char *str, int n);
int main()
{
    char str[100];
    int n;
    printf("Enter a string\n");
    scanf("%s",&str);
    for( n = 0; str[n] != '\0'; n++)
    {

    }
    reverse(str,n);
    puts(str);
    return 0;
}
void reverse(char *str,int n)
{
    printf("Length = %d\n",n);
    printf("Reversed :\n");
    int i;
    char ch;
    for(i = 0; i<n/2; i++)
    {
        ch = str[i];
        str[i] = str[n-i-1];
        str[n-i-1] = ch;
    }
}
```